# In Qualtrics, how to save a key response into an embedded data?

Tags: qualtrics

I have the code listed below. This was a code recommended by the Qualtrics support team before they updated their system. In this code, you remove the next button, and let the participants answer with key strokes,e.g. J or K.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();
var that = this;

Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
 var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 74: // 'j' was pressed
    choiceID = 1;
    break;
    case 75: // 'k' was pressed
    choiceID = 2;
    break;        
 }

 if (choiceID) {
   Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
   that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
   that.clickNextButton();
 }


});

});
```

I also created a Embedded Data called 'choiceID' from the Survey Flow section. I can see this new column in my final results.

I want to send the response key information (J as choiceID=1 or K as choiceID=2) to the results as an embedded data?

I am working on integrating the code below, which does not seem to be working.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("choiceID",choiceID);
```

Comment: Your code looks correct.  The setEmbeddedData line should go inside the if(choiceID). The embedded data field will be redundant with the question answer.

Comment: Thanks! actually after cleaning few typos, it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working version.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();
var that = this;

Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
var choiceID = null;
switch (e.keyCode) {
  case 74: // 'j' was pressed
  choiceID = 1;
  break;
  case 75: // 'k' was pressed
  choiceID = 2;
  break;        
  }

if (choiceID) {     
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("choiceID",choiceID);
Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
that.clickNextButton();
}

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to implement embedded data to see, in the data file, the results of the key press (See [It used to be possible to setChoiceValue in Qualtrics. Is there a workaround that does not involve embedded data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352749/it-used-to-be-possible-to-setchoicevalue-in-qualtrics-is-there-a-workaround-tha) ). The following works for me.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
this.hideNextButton();
this.hidePreviousButton();
var that = this;
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
  var choiceID = null;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 74: // 'j' was pressed
      choiceID = 1;
      break;
    case 75: // 'k' was pressed
      choiceID = 2;
      break;
  }
  if (choiceID) {
    Event.stopObserving(document, 'keydown', keydownCallback);
    that.setChoiceValue(choiceID, true);
    that.clickNextButton();
  }
});
});
```